# Invoice emails are not being sent

Tags: magento-1.6, invoice, paypal-express

I have `Magento 1.6.0.0` and I use `Paypal Express Checkout`. The issue is that Invoice emails are not automatically sent. It says at the invoice details page:

> the invoice email is not sent

Can someone tell me whats the issue here?

The Order confirmation emails are sent successfully and I think Paypal data is also getting captured via IPN (or by PDT) as I am getting "Payment Information" filled with data coming from paypal.

Let me know how to get this solved.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have solved this issue.. see my other related question:
(http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5980/paypal-ipn-and-invoice)

Answer (score 4):

config.xml

```
<global>
   <events>
        <sales_order_payment_pay>
            <observers>
                <some_module_node>
                    <class>Some_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>salesOrderPaymentPay</method>
                </some_module_node>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_payment_pay>
    </events>
</global>
```

Observer.php:

```
class Some_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function salesOrderPaymentPay($observer)
    {
        /**
         * @var $invoice Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice
         * @var $paymentMethod Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
         */
        $invoice       = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
        $paymentMethod = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance();
        if ($paymentMethod->getCode() == Mage_Paypal_Model_Config::METHOD_WPP_EXPRESS && !$invoice->getEmailSent()) {
            $invoice->sendEmail(TRUE);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ok, i am adding it `Mage_Paypal_Model_Observer`

Comment: also, which config.xml should I add it to?

Comment: app/code/local/Some/Module/etc/config.xml

Comment: I have created a config.xml at `\app\code\local\Mage\Paypal\Module\etc` I hope this works now...

Comment: no, didnt work... perhaps wrong directory.... can you please tell me exactly what directory to make config and observer for it to work?

Comment: You can add this to any module, or create new own module and add this observer. You should know how to create module and its structure, and how to attach event/observer to the module. If not do some googling.

Comment: I have actually solved it myself as I answered here:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5980/paypal-ipn-and-invoice