# Paypal IPN and invoice

Tags: magento-1.6, paypal-express

I have `Magento 1.6.0.0` and I use `Paypal Express Checkout`. The issue is that invoice emails are not automatically sent. It says at the invoice details page "*the invoice email is not sent*”.

Can someone tell me whats the issue here?

I looked at the IPN file at “**\app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Ipn.php**” and in the function **_registerPaymentCapture()** is generating ‘**NULL**’ at the line

```
$invoice = $payment->getCreatedInvoice()
```

Because of this, I cant do the regular hack recommended everywhere:

```
@$invoice->sendEmail();
```

Comment: you never should use @

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is how I have solved it myself !!

[file `\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Payment.php`]

```
public function registerCaptureNotification($amount)
{
    .
    .
    .
    // at the end right before return $this;

    // Custom Code - Send email on Invoice #-
    if (!$this->getIsTransactionPending()){
    if(!$this->getIsFraudDetected()){
    if($invoice)
    {
        @$invoice->sendEmail();
        @$invoice->setEmailSent(true);
    }
    }
    }
    //#-
}
```

However, this will only work with Paypal IPN being called and confirmed...